# Impute NaN value based on other data frame Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have data frame (DF1) with missing values and I want impute those missing values from a different data frame (DF2) while KEEPING the indexes and NOT sorting them (very important).
I am trying to find the most efficient way to do that.

DF1:

```
index  id  test
3      45   6.9
56     2    NA
1      789  8
29     12   4.7
```

DF2:

```
index  id  test
56     2    2.3
```

Result:

```
index  id  test
3      45   6.9
56     2    2.3
1      789  8
29     12   4.7
```

I tried this:

```
tempResult = pd.merge(DF1, DF2,on=id,how='outer',sort=False).set_index(DF1.index)
```

tempResult:

```
index  id  test_x  test_y
3      45   6.9    NA
56     2    NA     2.3
1      789  8      NA
29     12   4.7    NA
```

and then I need to go through all the values so i'm looking for more efficient way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `"index"`  is in fact the [`DataFrame.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html) here then you should just be able to use [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df1.fillna(df2)
```

If not, then may need to use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first like:

```
df1.set_index('index').fillna(df2.set_index('index'))
```

[out]

```
        id  test
index           
3       45   6.9
56       2   2.3
1      789   8.0
29      12   4.7
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

```
print(df1.combine_first(df2))
```

---

```
        id  test
index           
1      789   8.0
3       45   6.9
29      12   4.7
56       2   2.3
```

Comment: I have to keep the same order of indexes for other uses.

Comment: @anat just reindex, `df1.combine_first(df2).reindex(df1.index)` ?

Comment: @anat no problem, you could also try `df1.update(df2)` but this updates all columns(if df2 has same info for all the columns use `update()` ) and not only `NaN` , `combine_first()` was made just for that purpose. Cheers..!!